# get count of unread messages using imap php function

Tags: php, mysql, email, zend-framework

Actually I am using imap functions but the problem is the count I am getting is of all the emails I want count that give me unread mail count can anyone tell me how can I do it. I can delete the seen mail and then it is working fine but I want to keep the mail and read the unread one.

I am taking help from [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3324-PHP-Retrieve-e-mail-messages-into-a-MySQL-database.html)

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total_messages; $i++) {

    $email = $vars->email_get($i+1);
    $ismsgdb = $vars->db_add_message($email); // vars INSERTS EACH MSG INTO DATABASE
    #Get store dir
    $dir = $vars->dir_name();
    $id_log = $vars->add_db_log($email, 'Copy e-mail - start ');

    foreach($vars->partsarray as $part){

    if($part[text][type] == 'HTML'){
        #$message_HTML = $part[text][string];
        $vars->db_update_message($part[text][string], $type= 'HTML');
    }
    elseif($part[text][type] == 'PLAIN'){
        $message_PLAIN = $part[text][string];
        $vars->db_update_message($part[text][string], $type= 'PLAIN');
    }
    elseif($part[attachment]){
    #Save files(attachments) on local disc

    foreach(array($part[attachment]) as $attach){
        $attach[filename] = $vars->mimie_text_decode($attach[filename]);
        $attach[filename] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.]/i', '_', $attach[filename]);
        $vars->add_db_log($email, 'Start coping file:"'.strip_tags($attach[filename]).'"');

        $vars->save_files($vars->newid.$attach[filename], $attach[string]);
        $filename =  $dir.$vars->newid.$attach[filename];
        $vars->db_add_attach($attach[filename], $filename);
        $vars->update_db_log('<b>'.$filename.'</b>Finish coping:  "'.strip_tags($attach[filename]).'"', $vars->logid);
    }

    }elseif($part[image]){
    #Save files(attachments) on local disc

    $message_IMAGE[] = $part[image];

    foreach($message_IMAGE as $image){
        $image[filename] = $vars->mimie_text_decode($image[filename]);
        $image[filename] = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_\-\.]/i', '_', $image[filename]);
        $vars->add_db_log($email, 'Start coping file: "'.strip_tags($image[filename]).'"');


        $vars->save_files($vars->newid.$image[filename], $image[string]);
        $filename =  $dir.$vars->newid.$image[filename];
        $vars->db_add_attach($image[filename], $filename);
        $vars->update_db_log('<b>'.$filename.'</b>Finish  
        coping:"'.strip_tags($image[filename]).'"', $vars->logid);
        }

       }

     }
       $vars->spam_detect();
       $vars->email_setflag(); 
      //$vars->email_delete(); // WHEN I REMOVE vars THE SCRIPT WONT GRAB NEW EMAILS
      //$vars->email_expunge(); // WHEN I REMOVE vars THE SCRIPT WONT GRAB NEW EMAILS

      $vars->update_db_log('Finish coping', $id_log);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this code but i think it will run without error.You can try something like this :

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'yourid@gmail.com';
$password = 'xyz123';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
 echo count($emails);

imap_close($inbox);
```

Only pass unseen parameter to search function.For details please read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php).

Comment: i have tried this before but the thing is that it is returning me the total count although i have visited the mail before

Comment: After changing the parameter didn't effect ?

Answer (score 1):

After one day of work, ] found a solution. We need to replace `UNSEEM` with `UNREAD` like this:

```
$inbox = imap_open ("{".$serveur_entrant.$port.$protocole."}".$boite, $identifiant, $mot_de_passe);
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNREAD');
echo count($emails);
imap_close($inbox);
```